# Canvas drawing..strange behaviour

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, draw

I have a problem with the canvas element. The code is really simple, but if I switch from my tab to another and after i go back, what happens is shown in the figure. Anyone has an explanation for this?

```
var canvas = $('#image')[0];
canvas.height = 785;
canvas.width = 448;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

edit: I am using chrome, with firefox this doesn't happen..

[What happens http://matteociman.altervista.org/images/behaviour.png](http://matteociman.altervista.org/images/behaviour.png)

Comment: Your link isn't working for me.

Comment: Maybe this one will work..[link](http://matteociman.altervista.org/images/behaviour.png)

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing it now.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome..with Firefox for example this seems not to happen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively new bug introduced into the stable version of Google Chrome. It is also in the developer version (And has been for weeks) It gets worse if you open a developer console.

Last time I loaded up the nightly it was also broken, but they're definitely away of the problem.

For now, slightly resizing the window or disabling hardware acceleration in about:flags will fix the problem.

This bug might have been relevant, and I have only had the issue on machines with AMD video cards: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125246

Comment: This is not a great thing..thank you for the answer..hope that they will fix it before i finish my project..:)